# Merge all file .pkl to one file .pkl Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have file pickle in some folder. 1 Folder will have many file pickle and it will update everyday.

For example in signature folder have;
1.pkl
2.pkl
....
1000.pkl

i want to merge all in one file with automatically by id file. Have some solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dictionari file, just load it in 1 variable then convert to pkl data.

```
import os
import pickle

folder='signature/'
db = {}  
for filename in os.listdir(folder):  
    if filename.endswith('.pkl'):
        myfile = open(folder+filename,"rb")
        db[os.path.splitext(filename)[0]]= pickle.load(myfile)
        myfile.close()
        print(filename)

print(db)
myfile = open("merge/merge.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(db, myfile)
myfile.close()
```

Finally, i solved my problem. Thanks to my friend.